# Texture paint glitching stroke

Tags: texture-painting

I've been painting textures on a model with a normal map but one day it started to do a weird fading stroke that then turns to solid after a second or two. Happens only when texture paint opacity is set to 0 as shown in gif (even with the normal map removed from the material). I would assume its lag but the stroke itself is smooth. I was hoping to find a way to fix it, please help!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AU7dW.jpg

Using blender 2.8, Eevee rendering.
Problem first surfaced after redoing the lighting of the scene and adding a new glowing object (same drawing issue on it as well, same with and without the object). In the gif using a mouse, same issue with wacom pen.

Comment: Have you tried turning the number of threads from Automatic to 1? I had read somewhere that this might be cause for some lag issues when painting when it is using all the cpu cores.

Comment: Took a while to go trough settings and find a way to change the threads for cycles but that didnt seem to do the trick, thanks for trying to help though!

Comment: And after going trough the settings countless times i'm ashamed to admit the fix was merely changing the viewport samples to a low number other than 0. I hope i didnt waste your time!